# Atom Interfering Keymap Config?

Tags: atom-editor, keymaps

I have this in Atom my kepmap file:

```
'.editor':
   'ctrl-i': 'window:toggle-invisibles'

'.editor':
   'ctrl-t': 'editor:toggle-indent-guide'
```

ctrl-t works but ctrl-i doesn't.

Just deleting the

```
'.editor':
   'ctrl-t': 'editor:toggle-indent-guide'
```

makes ctrl-i work again.

Why would that be? How to I clear the interference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll notice both bindings **share the same class** even if they don't share the same keystroke, try putting them together like so:

```
'.editor':
   'ctrl-i': 'window:toggle-invisibles'
   'ctrl-t': 'editor:toggle-indent-guide'
```

And you could even be more specific to avoid having them overwritten whenever you install new packages, like so:

```
'.workspace .editor:not(.mini)':
   'ctrl-i': 'window:toggle-invisibles'
   'ctrl-t': 'editor:toggle-indent-guide'
```

That's just an example, you can be even more specific adding .pane, but the previous one does the job.

You can also use the `Key Binding Resolver` by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd><sub>(that's the "dot" or "period")</sub>, or querying the command palette by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and searching for `resolver`, bam you are there (that one you knew for sure, I just mention it for other people who may be reading this and may not be familiar with basic functionality).

The key binding resolver will help you monitor how other bindings may be interfering.

Look:

[image: an atom screenshot displaying the keybinding resolver pane opened below, also there's a hand noted commentary and some infantile doodle]

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Putting the two commands together under .editor was the fix. Thanks!